# Присвоение всем элементам с классом node обработчика события ondrag

Tags: jquery

Что не так в этом коде? Хочу присвоить всем элементам с классом node обработчик события ondrag.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.drag = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).ondrag = function () {
                alert('test');
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
$('.node').drag();
```

Comment: Где вы нашли `.ondrag` и `.drag`?

Comment: drag из головы это имя функции, а ondrag событие DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте функцию bind:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.drag = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).bind("drag", function (e) {
                alert('test');
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
$('.node').drag();
```

Comment: Нужно добавить событие DOM, в jQuery его нет. Возможно ли написать свое?